# Do I need to pass variables to threads through Thread?

Tags: python

Is there any real difference between these two?

1. Variables are accessed in the threaded function, but not passed to it through Thread(args)
2. Variables are passed to the threaded function through Thread(args)

```py
# 1
def do_something():
    event = Event()
    tracker = MyObject.instance()
    start_time = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())

    def threaded_function():
        current_time = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
        
        while True:
            if current_time - start_time > 30:
                tracker.put("too long")
                break
            elif event.is_set():
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(1)

    thread = Thread(target=threaded_function)
    thread.start()

    # Do something that may take more than 30 seconds 
    
    event.set()
```

```py
# 2
def do_something():
    event = Event()

    def threaded_function(tracker, start_time):
        current_time = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
        
        while True:
            if current_time - start_time > 30:
                tracker.put("too long")
                break
            elif event.is_set():
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(1)

    tracker = MyTracker.instance()
    start_time = datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())
    thread = Thread(target=threaded_function, args=(tracker, start_time))
    thread.start()

    # Do something that may take more than 30 seconds
    
    event.set()
```

Comment: Given that you only use the function to start one thread, there's little difference. #1 wouldn't allow you to have multiple threads with different starting times, because every thread's function would be using the same variable `start_time` local to `do_something`.

Comment: (The value of `start_time` is looked up in the enclosing scope each time it is accessed, as opposed to being "hard-coded" in the definition of `threaded_function`.)

Comment: (And the same applies to `tracker`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically speaking, there is little difference between the two, since you only start one thread.

In #1, `threaded_function` is a closure over two local variables in `do_something`. There would be no way to reliably vary those values between two or more threads, as any change to `tracker` or `start_time` would be visible inside *any* call to `do_something`.

In #2, `tracker` and `start_time` are local to `threaded_function`. They can be initialized to different values in each thread that runs `threaded_function`, and the values in one function are independent of values in another.